# Creating a class variable from a function. Python

Tags: class, variables, python-3.x

Alrighty, I am new to coding with python so please don't judge my examples too harshly. I was wondering if there was a way I could assign a class a variable from a function.

example:

```
class foo:
  blahCounter = 0

def addABlahDictToFoo( dictName, blahName, blahType ):
  ...
```

How do I get class foo into the fold here to append a variable and how would I append it to begin with?

Bonus question: How do I add an argument to a string I want to print?

```
print "Adding" ( dictName ) "to Foo."
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I don’t understand what you want to do. Can you try to explain it differently?

Comment: I'm trying to add a variable to a class using a function. Instead of explicitly adding it when I define the class. I need to be able to dynamically add a variable to a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to an object by just specifying it:

```
class MyClass:
    def setSomething (self, value):
        self.someVariable = value

x = MyClass()
x.setSomething('foo')
print(x.someVariable) # foo
```